# Solving coupled differential equations with time delay

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration, feedback

I'm trying to model the motion of a particle in a potential and incorporate feedback. The problem I'm having is adding a delay to the feedback. So, working in Matlab, I have a basic script which looks like:

```
clear all; close all;
qx = .3;
qy = .4;
qz = .5;
om_D = 1.2e8;
ep = 1e-10;

t = 0:1e-11:1e-5;

[t,rss]=ode45(@ion_test, t, [1e-7 .45 2e-7 -.45 0.5e-7 .45],[], qx, qy, qz, om_D, ep);
```

where `ion_test.m` is a function file which reads as follows:

```
function dr = ion_test(t,r, qx, qy, qz, om_D, ep)    
    dr = zeros(6,1);
    dr(1) = r(2);
    dr(2) = (2*qx*cos(om_D.*t) + ep.*2*r(3)*r(5));
    dr(3) = r(4);
    dr(4) = (2*qy*cos(om_D.*t) + ep.*2*r(1)*r(5));
    dr(5) = r(6);
    dr(6) = (2*qz*cos(om_D.*t) + ep.*2*r(1)*r(3));
end
```

So as you can see, the differential equations for each of the coordinates of `r` are coupled. The thing which I need to add is the ability for each equation to call upon the values of other coordinates at previous times, not just their current values. The purpose of this is to build in a delayed feedback mechanism. 
Any help very much appreciated!

Comment: plese, post a [mcve]

Comment: Hope this version is clearer

Comment: nope. I need to be able to copy paste it and run it

Comment: Ok, have adjusted again. Hopefully this is something straightforward now.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to my question was basically that I needed to use dde23 instead of ode45.